# C#, no Id yet for entity, need to save with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity/model defined int C#. There's an in Id on it. Nothing special. This is so standard I am almost certain I'm going to get flagged duplicate for this but I honestly cannot find another question about it.

I have a controller that expects an object with the properties of the entity.

```
public IActionResult Submit(MyModel model)
```

I'm basically just passing this in be saved by EF Core.

But... I get an error about not liking the `Id` being `null` before it even makes it inside the controller action. I know I can instantiate these and save them typically and they don't have an Id up front, under what circumstance would it complain about it being null?

> id: ["Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'id', line 1, position 258."]

Answer (score 0):

Right so about 9/10 of the way through this question (and way too much time head-scratching) I figured out exactly what it was. Leaving here in case anyone runs into the problem in the future - mostly likely me in about a month. Hello, future me.

There's no problem instantiating the entity for saving without supplying an Id. The issue was passing literally `id: null` in the post data, and the server trying to convert the null to an int.